# Can't reproduce example of using HoughLines from OpenCV for python

Tags: opencv

All functions from OpenCV properly works, but running this code don't give me expected result:

```
dave = cv2.imread('dave.png')
dave1 = cv2.cvtColor(dave,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dave2 = cv2.Canny(dave1,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
dave3 = dave2.copy()

lines = cv2.HoughLines(dave2,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(dave3,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(100,100,100),20)

cv2.imshow('image',dave3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code is almost as it is in [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)

Original image:

[image]

My result:

[image]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that dave3 is a gray level image and dave a colour image. You are trying to write a coloured line into a gray level image dave3, this does not make sense.

Try to write the lines into the colored image dave instead.

And the indentation at cv.line was missing. Furthermore, I have reduced the line width for drawing in that command from 20 to 2, similar to the original tutorial.

You may want to loop over line in lines, to draw all lines.

The code you are looking for would probably be:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

dave = cv2.imread('dave.jpg')
dave1 = cv2.cvtColor(dave,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dave2 = cv2.Canny(dave1,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(dave2,1,np.pi/180,200)
for line in lines:
    for rho,theta in line:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

        cv2.line(dave,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),0)

cv2.imshow('image',dave)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I included original image in my post. With your code I have only one line again.

Comment: I have modified the code to loop over all lines, not only plotting lines[0]. Your tutorial is wrong on this, the source only plots lines[0], while the result is showing all lines.

Comment: Not it works! Thanks.
In every tutorial and post here I have seen this `lines[0]` and it confused me.

Comment: lines is a list of all lines found by the Hough transformation. lines[0] is just the first line.